# How to receive notification in android if a data is inserted in the database

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, android-notifications

I have a mySQL database, and I created a simple android app that can display the data from the database using json. And I want to add the function wherein if a data is inserted in my database, the android app will be notified.

For example.I have two android app(App "A" and "B"). App "A" can Insert Data, and "B" can Display the data. I'm thinking of, everytime that App "A" Inserts a data, App "B" will be notified, and can refresh the current displayed data. I am thinking of refresh the list every certain time(5-10sec), but it seems to add more process time, and I think maybe refreshing it only when a data is inserted in the database would be better. Is there a way to do this? Hope that you can provide me some knowledge on how to do this. And if possible some example codes. Thank you.

Comment: You can use push notifications. You can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your backend is built using php, this is possible. I assumed that because you've set PHP as a tag.

Every time someone request to insert data to your php, you can insert it into MySQL and if insert went OK you could Google Cloud Messaging (GCM): https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Read documentation well, because GCM is not one-liner. It requires setup on Google console, your PHP server and Android app.